# Getting AuthFail exception with JSch 0.1.48 but not in 0.1.49 and newer with password authentication

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

Previously JSch 0.1.48 was working fine but recently it has stopped working and throwing an exception

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:484)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:162)
    at ftptrial.main.TestTop.main(TestTop.java:52)
```

When I change the version of JSch to 0.1.49, it works fine. But I am not able to figure out the reason why.

```
session = jsch.getSession(userName, hostName, portNumber);
session.setPassword(password);
session.connect();
```

Log for JSch 0.1.48:

```
INFO: Connecting to abc.defg.com port 22
INFO: Connection established
INFO: Remote version string: SSH-2.0-1.82_sshlib GlobalSCAPE
INFO: Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.48
INFO: CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
INFO: CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
INFO: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 is not available.
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
INFO: kex: server: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
INFO: kex: server: ssh-rsa
INFO: kex: server: twofish256-cbc,twofish-cbc,twofish128-cbc,blowfish-cbc,3des-cbc,arcfour,cast128-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes128-cbc
INFO: kex: server: twofish256-cbc,twofish-cbc,twofish128-cbc,blowfish-cbc,3des-cbc,arcfour,cast128-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes128-cbc
INFO: kex: server: hmac-sha1,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO: kex: server: hmac-sha1,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO: kex: server: zlib,none
INFO: kex: server: zlib,none
INFO: kex: server: 
INFO: kex: server: 
INFO: kex: client: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
INFO: kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
INFO: kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
INFO: kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
INFO: kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO: kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO: kex: client: none
INFO: kex: client: none
INFO: kex: client: 
INFO: kex: client: 
INFO: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
INFO: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT sent
INFO: expecting SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
INFO: ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
WARN: Permanently added 'abc.defg.com' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
INFO: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
INFO: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
INFO: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
INFO: Next authentication method: publickey
INFO: Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive,password
INFO: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
INFO: Authentications that can continue: password
INFO: Next authentication method: password
INFO: Disconnecting from abc.defg.com port 22
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
```

Log for JSch 0.1.54

```
INFO: Connecting to abc.defg.com port 22
INFO: Connection established
INFO: Remote version string: SSH-2.0-1.82_sshlib GlobalSCAPE
INFO: Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.54
INFO: CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
INFO: CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
INFO: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 is not available.
INFO: CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
INFO: kex: server: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
INFO: kex: server: ssh-rsa
INFO: kex: server: twofish256-cbc,twofish-cbc,twofish128-cbc,blowfish-cbc,3des-cbc,arcfour,cast128-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes128-cbc
INFO: kex: server: twofish256-cbc,twofish-cbc,twofish128-cbc,blowfish-cbc,3des-cbc,arcfour,cast128-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes128-cbc
INFO: kex: server: hmac-sha1,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO: kex: server: hmac-sha1,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO: kex: server: zlib,none
INFO: kex: server: zlib,none
INFO: kex: server: 
INFO: kex: server: 
INFO: kex: client: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
INFO: kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
INFO: kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc
INFO: kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc
INFO: kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO: kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO: kex: client: none
INFO: kex: client: none
INFO: kex: client: 
INFO: kex: client: 
INFO: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
INFO: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<1024) sent
INFO: expecting SSH_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
INFO: expecting SSH_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
INFO: ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
WARN: Permanently added 'abc.defg.com' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
INFO: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
INFO: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
INFO: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
INFO: Next authentication method: publickey
INFO: Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive,password
INFO: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
INFO: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
Connection success
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both JSch 0.1.48 and JSch 0.1.49 are 5 years old. Do not use them!

Use the latest version of JSch (0.1.55 as of now).

---

I cannot explain the difference conclusively without more information, but as 0.1.54 actually successfully uses keyboard interactive authentication (comparing to unsuccessful password authentication in 0.1.48), I'd blame this change in `UserAuthKeyboardInteractive.start`:

- 0.1.48:

  ```
  prompt[0].toLowerCase().startsWith("password:")){
  ```
- 0.1.49:

  ```
  prompt[0].toLowerCase().indexOf("password:") >= 0){
  ```

Your code is actually attempting password authentication. But JSch has a heuristics, that if it gets keyboard interactive authentication prompt for a single password, it will use keyboard interactive authentication, not password authentication.

I'd guess that the prompt coming from your server is like

> user password:

So 0.1.48 `startsWith` check does not capture the prompt, while 0.1.49 and newer `indexOf` check does.

If you do not want to rely on this heuristics, you should change your code to actually use keyboard interactive authentication.
See http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/UserAuthKI.java.html